# React — inline onfocus placeholder = ''

Tags: input, reactjs, toggle, placeholder

I typically use an inline onfocus / blur to toggle placeholder text in inputs. Like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Name'"/>
```

This doesn't seem to work in React and I'm wondering what is the "correct" way of handling placeholder toggles in React.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You still can do it inline with React:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  placeholder="Name" 
  onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ""} 
  onBlur={(e) => e.target.placeholder = "Name"} />
```

Comment: it's not working for me? it's because i use redux-form? maybe redux-form overwrite my handlers?